# JavaScript: new Date(Date.parse("A 49"))

Tags: javascript

```
new Date(Date.parse("A49"))
// Invalid Date

new Date(Date.parse("A 49"))
// Fri Jan 01 2049 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)

new Date(Date.parse("Aasdfashdkfjahslkdf 49"))
// Fri Jan 01 2049 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
```

Why "A 49" is valid DateTime?

Comment: Note that `Date.parse` is unreliable and can work quite differently in different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The parser ignored your A *(because your A can be something like a separator or just some user text that has no relation to the date)*, and just picked the number and took it as the year. But if you add a letter to the number the parser cant recognize it as a number, and consequently can not convert it to an date.

Examples:

```
new Date(Date.parse("A 49"))
//Fri Jan 01 2049 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

new Date(Date.parse("OTHER 49"))
//Fri Jan 01 2049 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

new Date(Date.parse("OTHER 10"))
//Mon Oct 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

new Date(Date.parse("OTHER 10a"))
//Invalid Date

new Date(Date.parse("OTHER 10 10"))
//Wed Oct 10 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

[More about Date.parse("...")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's parsing `A 49` and extracting only `49` and assuming it's start of 2049.